# Loop Problem while reading a text file in C

Tags: c, loops, file

Hi guys i wanna read a text file word by word and count the words while doing it and then pass the words and numbers to my linked list.

But i have a loop problem. I can't escape from the infinite loop.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char kelime[100];
    char kelime2[100];
    long a = 0;

    FILE * dosya = fopen("oku.txt", "r");
    
    while(1)
    {
        fseek(dosya,a,SEEK_CUR);
        
        if(feof(dosya))
        {
            break;  
        }
        
        while(fscanf(dosya, "%99[^ \n]", kelime) == 1)
        {
            printf("%s \n",kelime);
            a = ftell(dosya);
        }
        
        while(1)
        {
            fscanf(dosya, "%s" , kelime2);
            printf("%s \n",kelime2);
            
            if((strcmp(kelime, kelime2))== 0)
            {
                // Things to do...
            }
            
            memset(kelime2,0,sizeof(kelime2));
            
            if(feof(dosya))
            {
                rewind(dosya);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(dosya);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not a simple `while (fscanf(dosya, "%99s", kelime) == 1) { /* Add word to linked list... */ }`

Comment: I don't know im tryna understand files and  (fscanf(dosya, "%99[^ \n]", kelime) == 1)  This is what i found on stackoverflow. What im tryna do is basically read each word and count them, then pass to linked list. Can u fix my code pls?

Comment: Using `feof` this way is incorrect and not a good idea. `feof` is true after an attempt to read past the end of file. There are very many stack overflow answers that explain this. You should use other means of terminating your loop(s). You can, for example, use the return value of `fscaf` as SomeProgrammerDude has shown.

Comment: Can you please fix and rewrite my code? I tried   (fscanf(dosya, "%99s", kelime) == 1)  this but didn't really helped. Im not good at C and my english is not really good

Comment: `fseek` returns a value that is worth checking [fseek](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

To read any kind of space-delimited word, all you need is something like:

```
while (fscanf(dosya, "%99s", kelime) == 1)
{
    // Do something with the "word" in kelime
}
```

The [`scanf` family of functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) all return the number of *conversions* it successfully made. With a single conversion specifier it can only return `1` on success, `0` if the specifier could not be matched (should never happen in this case) or `-1` on error or end of file.

The loop will simply read all words in the input file until the end of the file.

Putting it together in a program that reads and print all words, it would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *dosya = fopen("oku.txt", "r");
    if (dosya == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not open file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char kelime[100];
    size_t counter = 0;

    while (fscanf(dosya, "%99s", kelime) == 1)
    {
        printf("Read word #%zu: %s\n", ++counter, kelime);
    }

    fclose(dosya);

    printf("There was a total of %zu \"words\" in the file\n", counter);
}
```

---

A little explanation for the `%zu` format specifier for [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf):

The `u` is the base format (it's really `%u`), and stands for **u**nsigned integer. The `z` prefix tells `printf` that the corresponding argument is really a `size_t` value.

The type [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is a standard C type that is used for all kinds of sizes, counters and indexes. It's an unsigned integer of unspecified size.

Comment: Thanks but what im trying to do is finding every word and how many times they repeat themselves. Not to find how many word there is in file. And i can't read whole file like that. I need to read word by word.

Comment: @linnix05 We're not here to give you a finished solution to your full assignment. Using my example as a base you should solve the problem you ask about, the problem with reading words not working as expected. Now it's up to you to do something useful with this base.

Comment: @linnix05 the example does read "word" by "word".  Did you try it?